# jQuery tabs size according to the content size

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I wanted to know how to adjust the jQuery tabs size according to the contained div inside of a tab, and not by the window size. What changes I should do in the CSS?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the width of the containing div and you are ok if i understand correctly what you mean

http://jsfiddle.net/jDZhP/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` properties of javascript to calculate height, width of the contained div inside of a tab.